# How can I have fewer, larger icons on the home screen?

Tags: home-screen, app-icons, samsung-galaxy-j3

I am helping an older relative transfer data to a replacement phone.  Both the old and new phones are Samsung Galaxy J3 Eclipses.  Here's a screenshot I took of the original phone home screen.  Note the top row appears to be a width of 4 grid slots, and the next two rows have 3 apps each:
[image]

This is desirable for both the large icons and to avoid information overload.  It's obviously possible, but looking through the settings I only see 4x4, 4x5 and 5x5 settings for the grid layout.  How can I replicate the previous layout?

Comment: Samsung devices have a screen layout called "Easy Mode". I don't believe it is new, and may be standard across their devices. I have seen it on at least the ones I have used in the past few years. Look for it under the Display settings.

Comment: @wbogacz, that's it! I just posted an answer using your suggestion, but if you want to post one of your own I'll delete mine and give you the reputation.

Comment: Your self-answer is OK by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `Easy Mode`, accessible through `Settings` -> `Display`. I had assumed that `Easy Mode` meant "hide advanced settings" but it actually means "Make big icons and use a default home screen layout".

[image]